# have this php query also show an html link

Tags: php, html, href

can this code snippet be modified to reveal html coding?

```
<?php $_option = $this->getOption() ?>
<?php echo  $this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()) ?>
```

it is showing a title but in that title i have an href:

```
<a href="http://link" target="otherwindow">link</a>
```

instead of it appearing as a link it just shows me the code.
i'd like it to be a clickable link.

possible?

Comment: this is the original code snippet

    <?php echo  $this->htmlEscape($_option->getTitle()) ?>

Comment: <?php echo $this->getOption()->getTitle(); ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just remove the $this->htmlEscape() and leave the $_option->getTitle()

The escape function is to provide just the functionality of not being able to use (or inject)  html commands or javascript.

Comment: great.
works exactly as i want.

i'm using it to modify a magento install and i have very little knowledge of php (obviously) and my google searches of the snippet were not helpful.

thanks for the rapid response!